# Parsing a complicated string as DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

Can someone tell me how should I approach converting the following format to a proper `DateTime` object?

```
11:50:46 AM on Wednesday, October 19, 2011
```

Comment: Have you read this article?
<http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx>

Comment: DateTime.TryParse will do that if you pass in a format string. Might be easier to work that out by formatting a datetime until you get this format and then plugging it in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
        string s = "11:50:46 AM on Wednesday, October 19, 2011";
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(s, 
            "hh:mm:ss tt on dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```