# Parse DateTime From Odd Format

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing a complicated string as DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433480/parsing-a-complicated-string-as-datetime)

I have a string date with time that I'd like to parse into a DateTime. I'm not quite sure how to tackle it because of the odd format. Help is appreciated.

Example: Mon Mar 24 13-42-30 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) should do what you want:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "Mon Mar 24 13-42-30 2008",
    "ddd MMM dd HH-mm-ss yyyy",
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Can someone tell me the difference between using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, like the other answers? I was assuming things like the day name and month name might need to be parsed in their native language. Thanks.

Comment: This one won't actually work, `hh` is 12 hour format, `HH` is 24 hour format.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var theDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "Fri Jul 13 13-42-30 2012", 
    "ddd MMM dd HH-mm-ss yyyy", 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Date string formatting options can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

That format doesn't seem all that odd, but you could probably easily handle it by using [DateTime.ParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss).  Of course, it assumes that the format remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

try this way please

```
string format ="ddd MMM dd hh-mm-ss yyyy";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(format, dateString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```